# apt-get update could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt

I am facing a strange issue. It can not resolve a target server with `apt-get`. But with `curl`, I can get a return from it. Details please find the images.

BTW, I tried 'IPv4' force, too; but, it also does not work.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure it's `archive.ubuntu.com` and not archieve.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Did you say `archieve.ubuntu.com`? Well, it is incorrect. It is `archive.ubuntu.com`.

**Method 1**

You can change it by typing in the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archieve.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**Method 2**

Or, if you are not familiarised with complex terminal commands, type this more simple command in the terminal:

```
sudo gedit '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```

Then, click on Find, and type `archieve.ubuntu.com`. Replace all those entries with `archive.ubuntu.com`. When you're done, save the file. Then, you can exit.

When you completed it with one of the above methods, update the apt cache by typing in the terminal: `sudo apt update`.

I hope for the best!

Comment: Hi Bajiru, it is my miss-typing here.In my source list, i have archive.ubuntu.com. My issue is apt-get update could not resolve it but curl can access it as the attached picture displayed.

Comment: @Sanchelz Can you send me a screenshot, then?

Comment: hi,please click on 'enter image description here'